# Filter row by each column value in data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have this dataframe that has some automotive brands and models. I would like to mask it by all of the brands inside the first column. They will however repeat since there are quite some models made by the same brand. From that mask, I would like to run some percentage calculations.

I need however to do this with every brand there present at the first column.

This is what I did so far.

Extracted all of the items for the first column and got them inside a list and then removed all the duplicates. I cannot find a way of getting a loop to obtain a mask and then being able to run it for my statistical purposes.

Here's how the DataFrame looks like:

```
Brand,value,rating
Renault Captur,81.500.000,70
Renault Duster (B),84.000.000,70
Renault Kangoo,61.900.000,70
Renault Sandero (A),50.900.000,70
Renault Kwid,43.800.000,60
Renault  Logan (A),61.800.000,70
Renault  Stepway (A),67.700.000,70
Renault  Sandero (B),50.900.000,40
Renault Logan (B),61.800.000,50
Renault Stepway (B),67.700.000,50
Renault Duster (A),67.800.000,0
Chevrolet Onix HB,69.300.000,100
Chevrolet Onix Plus,70.700.000,100
Chevrolet New Aveo (A),37.000.000,70
```

I need to filter all Renault, Chevrolet and so on and so forth. I get that this is possible manually using each brand and creating a mask. I wonder if there's a way to loop/automate this filter using each brand present on the "Brand" Column.

Comment: what is your expected output  ?

Comment: It's not clear why you need to do this. Why not split `Brand` into `Brand` and `Model`? Why not then groupby `Model` and perform your calculations on each group?

Comment: "mask it by all the brands" doesn't really make a whole lot of sense... do you mean that you want to look at rows in the dataframe which correspond to each model and "mask" the rest of the models out, model by model? Like, you want to look at all Renault cars and ignore the others, then look at all Chevy cars and ignore the others?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to separate the 'Brand Name' and 'Model Name' into separate columns. Then you can `groupby` on 'Brand Name' to mask the 'Model Name'.

```
cars = pd.read_csv('cars.csv')
#Split Brand and Model Name
cars['Brand Name'] = [car.split(' ', 1)[0] for car in cars['Brand']]
cars['Model Name'] = [car.split(' ', 1)[1].strip() for car in cars['Brand']]
#Convert 'value' to integer
cars['value'] = [int(car[:-4].replace('.','')) for car in cars['value']]
```

After the conversions, the data looks like this.

```
                     Brand  value  rating Brand Name    Model Name
0           Renault Captur  81500      70    Renault        Captur
1       Renault Duster (B)  84000      70    Renault    Duster (B)
2           Renault Kangoo  61900      70    Renault        Kangoo
3      Renault Sandero (A)  50900      70    Renault   Sandero (A)
4             Renault Kwid  43800      60    Renault          Kwid
5       Renault  Logan (A)  61800      70    Renault     Logan (A)
6     Renault  Stepway (A)  67700      70    Renault   Stepway (A)
7     Renault  Sandero (B)  50900      40    Renault   Sandero (B)
8        Renault Logan (B)  61800      50    Renault     Logan (B)
9      Renault Stepway (B)  67700      50    Renault   Stepway (B)
10      Renault Duster (A)  67800       0    Renault    Duster (A)
11       Chevrolet Onix HB  69300     100  Chevrolet       Onix HB
12     Chevrolet Onix Plus  70700     100  Chevrolet     Onix Plus
13  Chevrolet New Aveo (A)  37000      70  Chevrolet  New Aveo (A)
```

Now, you can groupby and use whichever statistic you need.

```
#Use groupby to get the required statistic
cars.groupby('Brand Name')['value'].mean() #Average 'value' of each brand
cars.groupby('Brand Name')['rating'].mean() #Average 'rating' of each brand
```

Comment: Is there any way to use the groupby with every brand name automatically or I should set a mask for all of the brands for which I would need the data from?

Comment: ```cars.groupby('Brand Name')['value'].mean()``` will groupby on all available brands. If I understand correctly you want the groupby to work for all brands i.e. Renault, Chevrolet etc. Is that what you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, I need to group all the available brands. Also, nice catch and thanks for the suggestion on splitting the brands from the model. Will do it and come back to see

Comment: If the solution works please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: It is returning the mean and not the percentage of the brands. The value should be different.